# How to prevent decimal.TryParse convert "," to "."?

Tags: c#, parsing

This is my code:

```
string myValue = "0,203";

decimal.TryParse(myValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out myValueAsDecimal;
```

...

```
myValueAsDecimal is 0.203 now
```

Is it possible that `myValueAsDecimal` has 0,203 after `TryParse` or the internal representation of `decimal` is always 0.203 and I need to format GUI output if I need 0,203?

Comment: It has neither a comma or a period, it is stored as a representation.

Comment: Internal representation of numbers is always binary. The textual (human) representation depends on the culture you specify (or not specify). To display the number with specific decimal point, you have to pass the right culture to ToString method or other method you use to format. To assign a value you have to use the dot as decimal point, because ti is the syntax of the programming language.

Comment: MIkroDel, I would add that you should probably not try to force the user to use one decimal separator, your application should support whatever culture they are using. Users may not be familiar that different cultures use a different decimal separator and definitely won't be trying to enter their own numbers with a foreign separator

Comment: @Sayse it is possible to make input with . or with , and both forms are allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible that myValueAsDecimal has 0,203 after TryParse

No. It's just a number - it has no concept of a text format. To think about it another way with a simpler type, consider these two lines of code:

```
int x = 0x100;
int y = 256;
```

Are those two values the same? Yes, they represent the same number. If you convert the values of `x` and `y` to strings, by default they will both end up as "256" - but they could both end up as "100" if you request a hex representation.

It's important to distinguish between the real value of a variable and a textual representation. Very few types (none that I can think of immediately) carry around information about a textual representation with them - so for example, a `DateTime` can be parsed from a variety of formats, but has no "memory" of an original text format. It's just a date and time, which could then be formatted according to any format.

If you *need* to maintain the idea of "a decimal number and the culture in which it was originally represented" then you should create your own class or struct for that pairing. It's not present in `decimal` itself.

Comment: Thats mean that to have 0,203 or 0.203 I have to work with my GUI? For example format output etc..

Comment: @MikroDel: I have no idea how to interpret your comment, I'm afraid. But yes, if you want to distinguish between "0,203" and "0.203" which have been parsed as the same `decimal` number, you'll need to remember that change in some value *other* than the `decimal` itself. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do though.

Comment: I have string input in form 0,203 or 0.203 depending on the selecting culture of the system.

This input should be stored in database as decimal and also shown as an ouput in form of 0,203 or 0.203 also depending on the culture.

Comment: @MikroDel: Why don't you just *format* the value according to the culture of the user reading it? Presumably that may be different to the culture of the original user... if someone in France enters "0,203" I'd still (in the UK) want to see "0.203"...

Comment: Thats what I really need to do I think. Ok thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal d = 0.203m;

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));        // decimal point: dot
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))); // default decimal point: dot
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"))); // default decimal point: comma
```

Result:

```
0,203
0.203
0.203
0,203
```

Comment: what is the difference between CurrentCulture and InstalledUICulture?

Comment: You should explain what you are attempting to answer here. The OP appears to be asking what separator the *decimal* has

Comment: Decimal (and other numeric types) has no separators. It's added after converting to string (with ToString() method). Default ToString() method uses decimal point of your computer selected culture.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `CurrentCulture` has `,` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and that's why your parsing succeed.

*Actually*, `0.203` and `0,203` are the same as value. Only matter is their *textual* representation when you print it.

If you wanna get your value as a `0,203` representation, you can use a culture that has `,` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator`.

For example, my culture (`tr-TR`) has a `,`. When you represent your decimal with it, you will get `0,203`.

```
string myValue = "0,203";
decimal myValueAsDecimal;
decimal.TryParse(myValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out myValueAsDecimal);
myValueAsDecimal.ToString(new CultureInfo("tr-TR")).Dump(); // 0,203
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `Decimal` is the same regardless of the Culture, it's

0.203

what changes is its String representation (decimal separator in your case), so
if you want to change *decimal separator* and don't want to change the Culture
you can just assign *NumberDecimalSeparator* in your custom `NumberFormatInfo` e.g.

```
  Decimal d = 0.203M;

  NumberFormatInfo myNumberInfo = new NumberFormatInfo() {
    NumberDecimalSeparator = "," // Comma, please
  };

  String result = d.ToString(myNumberInfo); // "0,203"
```